# Getting the location when the device is locked

Tags: android, location

I am trying to get location. When device is unlocked every thing works fine, but when device is locked then coordinates do not come.

Here is example of my service:

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        startForeground(1131, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
                .setContentText("App")
                .setContentTitle("App Service")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.enter_icon)
                .build());

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        startCheckLocation()
    }

    private void startCheckLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(interval);
        locationRequest.setInterval(interval);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mPendingIntent);
    }

    public static void start(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

}
```

I tried use getBroadcast() instead of getService() method, but it works in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I get location data via FirebaseJobDispatcher (google recommend to use WorkManager but it alpha for now).
I start the job that fire every 20 minutes, request location and store it to db.
You can look example of FirebaseJobDispatcher here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleLocation liberary for getting current latitude and longitude.

add below liberary in your build.gradle(Module:app) file

```
implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1'
```

And use below code in your service class

```
SimpleLocation simpleLocation = new SimpleLocation(LocationService.this);

        double lat = simpleLocation.getLatitude();
        double lon = simpleLocation.getLongitude();
```

don't forget to add LOCATION permission in your Manifest file.